# SpriteKit and combining multiple drags for a single rotation

Tags: ios, xcode, rotation, sprite-kit, trigonometry

What I'm attempting to recreate is the draggable arrow that's used in the popular iOS game called "Fragger", complete with both adjusting the rotation AND the strength of the pull all at the same time based on a finger drag but using SpriteKit - I believe they did it in Cocos2D.

I'll start by saying that I've honestly spent many weeks relearning trigonometry (http://www.mathsisfun.com/ is a great resource) and combing through Ray Wenderlich's tutorials (http://www.raywenderlich.com/35866/trigonometry-for-game-programming-part-1) but I can't find a solution for executing a "collective" drag rotation AND strength on a SpriteKit object.

Yes, it's relatively easy to set an anchor point and rotate that object (I'm using an arrow) so that it's pointing at your finger and thanks to Ray, I've got a really smooth action utilizing the following:

```
float angleRadians = atan2f(firstFingerTouchY - _arrow.position.y, firstFingerTouchX - _arrow.position.x);
float angleDegrees = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angleRadians);
float rotateDegreesPerSecond = 180 / 0.5; // Would take 0.5 seconds to rotate 180 degrees, or half a circle
float degreesDiff = (angleCurrent - angleDegrees) * 1.0;
float rotateDuration = fabs(degreesDiff / rotateDegreesPerSecond);
```

however, that's only part of the equation ...

Again, the first drag is fine as the angle of rotation is derived from the fulcrum of the arrow (it's anchor point) and where ever my finger ends up. However, let's say due to the limit of the screen size I can't get the angle I desire in a single drag, so I lift up my finger and then place it back down to continue the drag? Well I can't use the above mentioned code because as soon as I place my finger down for the second time, the arrow's rotation jumps over to where my finger now starts - again ending the same way.

So I thought the solution would be to not use the anchor point of the arrow at all, but instead use the initial finger touchpoint (as the new anchor) and calculate the arrow's angle based on that touchpoint and where ever my finger moves to? That works in theory, however when you then try to factor in the "strength draw" aspect that's represented in "Fragger" (where pulling the finger closer or farther away from the arrow adjusts the strength of the grenade throw), then you're not moving your finger towards the arrow to weaken the pull, but instead towards where ever you initially touched - which is not only visually difficult but as a bonus creates a lot of rotational jerky-ness as you get your finger closer to the origin.

I've been working on it for about a month now (did I mention that I hate math) trying to create a homogenized method (SIN ... COS ... TAN ... I hate you all!) to do the following:

1. First pull will rotate the arrow based on the direction of the pull but NOT automatically point to your finger (initial angle)
2. The ability to lift my finger up, place it back down and drag to ADD TO or SUBTRACT FROM the current rotation of the arrow. (delta angle)
3. The drag of my finger towards or away from the anchor of the arrow (relative to the current angle of the arrow) will adjust the strength of the "pull" accordingly. For example, if the arrow is already pointing straight up, then continuing the drag straight up would increase the strength and down would decrease the strength respectively. (hypotenuse derived from arrow anchor point).
4. I also need to be able to use another finger (2 finger touch) to assist in the rotation/strength calculation, so that adds even more chaos into my cluster ...

If you've ever played the 'Fragger' game, you'll recognize the complexity of this single finger action which is also it's functional beauty. I can get pieces of it working - I can rotate it, I can adjust a color mask to indicate strength - but not all of it working together. Perhaps I'm going about it completely wrong, however every example I find online stops at simply rotating an object to point to your finger with every new touch drag ending with the same results.